# How to resolve KeyError: 'PUNKTSIDE_FIN'

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy, anaconda3

I saw other questions on this topic but none of those solve my problem. I haven't installed anaconda in it's default location 'c:\anaconda3' ALSO I am using VSCode for development. When I run my code which is very simple

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

I get error(listed last below). Being new to all this I don't know where to start. Please advise...

---

**Information**:

```
(base) C:\Users\ashish>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : c:\Software\Installed\anaconda3
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\ashish\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\ashish\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : c:\Software\Installed\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : c:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ashish\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : c:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\ashish\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

---

I am using VSCode and when I try to go to python prompt from built in terminal I get following error

```
C:\Projects\Internal Data Mining>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Although from conda prompt I have activated 'base'

---

I installed Spacy and en_core_web_sm, en_core_web_lg packages information is below:

```
spacy                     2.0.12           py37h8300f20_0
spacy-model-en_core_web_lg 2.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_sm 2.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
```

---

**Main error**:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Projects\Internal Data Mining\SpacyTutorial.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Projects\Internal Data Mining\SpacyTutorial.py", line 16, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 15, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 114, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 135, in load_model_from_package
    return cls.load(**overrides)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 173, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 156, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 653, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    deserializers[name] = lambda p, proc=proc: proc.from_disk(p, vocab=False)
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 643, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.from_disk
  File "C:\Software\Installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 632, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.from_disk.load_tag_map
  File "morphology.pyx", line 56, in spacy.morphology.Morphology.__init__
  File "attrs.pyx", line 147, in spacy.attrs.intify_attrs
KeyError: 'PUNCTSIDE_FIN'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
spacy                     2.0.12           py37h8300f20_0
spacy-model-en_core_web_lg 2.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_sm 2.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
```

That version of spacy (2.0.*) is not compatible with those models (2.2.*). Try starting with a new conda environment and installing spacy from `conda-forge`, where the most recent version should be 2.2.3.